# Will Google warn me in this case?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I am connected to a network N1, in which there are many devices, including mine.

My device is DM with internal IP address 192.168.43.26
There is another device D2(not mine) with internal IP address 192.168.23.6
The router/server of N1 has public IP address 100.24.56.23 and is connected to the Internet.
Now, if I access my email account from my device within the network, the IP sent to the Gmail server will be 100.24.56.23.

And if someone gets to know my email ID and password and accesses my account from D2, then also, the IP address sent to the Gmail server will be 100.24.56.23.

This means that Gmail server will think that same device has accessed my account and not warn me of a "new device sign-in".

Am I right? If not, what is the reality? If yes, a hacker can secretly access any account like this(if he knows password), which is not safe. How can we prevent this?

Comment: What makes you think Google identifies devices by IP address?

Comment: Whenever I sign in with a new device, it gives me a warning email with the IP address of that device.

Comment: That's to help you determine if the access is legitimate or not. It doesn't follow that that's why Google thought the device was new.

Comment: See the last paragraph of my question, and please answer accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you try signing in with two different devices from your local network and see what happens? This question is very easy for you to find out the answer yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is seeking information on how Google identifies devices to allow access to a google account

Comment: You have no control over how Google recognizes computers attempting to access your account. The details are of course undocumented. Once someone has your email ID and password it's security is already seriously compromised. Don't let it happen. Give the account a good password, don't tell anyone what it is, and change it regularly.

Comment: This question just flashed in my mind, it's not like someone knows my password.

Answer (score 1):

Google did not identify you according to your ip address but it identify you according to cookies and session details it saves on your browser.
Whenever you login, it show your ip just for your convenience so you can identify the device easily.